# Installed Apps: Installing Django-Simple-History

Tags: python, django

I am [following the tutorial](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#install) for installing `django-simple-history` but am lost at what to put in my `installed_apps` `settings.py`. As the tutorial fails to mention anything, are specific apps to be imported required to be in my `settings.py`? [This test](https://github.com/treyhunner/django-simple-history/blob/master/runtests.py) further confuses me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to enable django-simple-history put the following in your installed apps:

```
'simple_history'
```